# logger не создает файл и не логирует события из теста

Tags: python, логирование, pytest

Есть функция в отдельном файле:

```
def write_in_log_info(text):
    logging.basicConfig(filename="sample.txt", level=logging.INFO,  format='%(asctime)s - %(levelname)s : %(message)s')
    logging.info(text)
```

В тесте обращение к этой функции выглядит так:

```
write_in_log_info("Выбрали случайного противника")
```

Но лог файл не создается и info туда не записывается, как можно это исправить ?

Comment: Если вызывать данную функцию из другого фала, то logging отрабатывает нормально

Answer (score 1):

Вам нужно задать кодировку записываемого файла. В противном случае логгер отказывается записывать utf-8 в файл, и, более того, может "забыть" хэндлер в памяти.
Попробуйте так:

```
import logging
def write_in_log_info(text):
    logging.basicConfig(handlers=[logging.FileHandler('sample.txt', 'w', 'utf-8')], 
    level=logging.INFO,  format='%(asctime)s - %(levelname)s : %(message)s')
    logging.info(text)

write_in_log_info("Выбрали случайного противника")
```

> 2019-10-02 23:21:02,923 - INFO : Выбрали случайного противника

Comment: Теперь файл создается, спасибо, но текст все равно не записывается а него

Comment: Странно то, что из теста функция вызывается и не отрабатывает как надо, а если вызывать функцию из любого другого файла, то все нормально отрабатывает и записывает

Comment: из какого теста?